# Implementing Selenium tests automation via Jenkins for Maven project

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, headless-browser, xserver

I am trying to integrate selenium tests suite (Maven) with jenkins and I am using chrome headless browser but facing error as below.

```
[2114:2114:0905/122912.875011:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(239)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[2114:2114:0905/122912.875064:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

The chrome driver and google binaries installed are same.

Below code has been implemented inside Drivermodule.java file for headless browser.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/google-chrome");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("headless");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

I am using Amazon Linux 2 server for running jenkins node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/google-chrome"
```

In the above line, it looks like you are setting the browser path and not driver's path.

You need to download the `chromedriver` for `linux` and set the path of it as below:

```
"webdriver.chrome.driver","/usr/bin/chromedriver"
```